# How to insert new row without duplicating existing data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to insert rows in my table like so:
my columns are student,subject,class,teacher,level. Primary key is (student,subject). The table contains all the students, but the Math subject is missing for some of them, so I want to add it without duplicating the ones that already have it.

I've tried this but it gives me unique constraint violated:

```
insert into table (student,subject,class,teacher,level)
select a.student, 'math', null, null, null
from   table  a
where  a.student in (select distinct student from table where subject not in 'math') 
and    (a.student,a.subject) not in (select student,subject from table);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you basically need `select distinct`:

```
insert into table (student, subject) 
    select distinct a.student, 'math'
    from table a
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table a2
                      where a2.student = a.student and
                            a2.subject = 'math'
                     );
```

Comment: No ,it gives 0 raws inserted.

Comment: @Blue . . . Duh.  The subquery should be checking for `'math'`.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `minus`:

```
insert into course_students (student, subject) 
select student, 'Math' from course_students
minus
select student, subject from course_students;
```

This would would need extending a little if you wanted to include other columns in the `insert`:

```
insert into course_students (student, subject, class, teacher, course_level)
select student, subject, '101', 'Naomi', 1
from   ( select student, 'Math' as subject from course_students
         minus
         select student, subject from course_students );
```